# How to automatically resubmit an R script to Torque/Moab after hitting the wall-clock time limit? R Torque

Tags: r, torque

I have an R script to be run using Torque/Moab. However, the wall-clock time limit is much shorter than the time required for the script to finish. The script cannot be parallelized anymore because of the nature of problem to be solved.

I modified the script to make backups of the workspace on specific intervals, and it resumes from the backup to continue the calculations.

However, I need a solution to automatically resubmit the script back to the Torque/Moab scheduler after hitting the wall-clock time limit as long as it is required.

Thanks.

Comment: You could have a second lightweight script running that monitors the backup folder. When it detects a file has been created, it will then load the the backup, and resubmit the script back to the Torque/Moab scheduler.

Comment: Thanks. However, because the calculations of this code do not proceed linearly, I cannot set the backup intervals very close to the wall-clock time limit, otherwise it could finish without making any backup in some cases. Actually, I set the backup intervals around 0.1 of that of the limit. Also, please note that there are several parallel processes running asynchronously with respect to each other in the script that makes it more complex.

Comment: Maybe check out the `ruffus` package for `python`, it handles this stuff. You may be able to use it to manage your R sessions. https://code.google.com/p/ruffus/

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. As my walltime limit is 48 hours, I am doing resubmit manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to power to increase your walltime @ submit? if so you can do to something like this in your submit script:

`#PBS -l walltime='00:00:00:00" #( DD:HH:min:SS)`

If not than i agree with Manetheran where you will have to write a small client to check.

Comment: Thanks. However, the walltime limit is 48 hours in my case.

Comment: I think the walltime limit is usually set for a particular queue. However you can check with the admin if other queue has longer walltime limit (e.g. qlong queue).

Answer (score 0):

The standard thing to do is to make a runscript that submits itself.  This is called chaining.  As a bare-bones bash example, suppose the following script were `/path/to/script.sh` and that JOB_ID represents the variable that refers to your particular Torque setup (probably `PBS_JOBID`?)

```
#!/bin/bash
#MSUB OPTIONS...

#(
#sleep 60 #for example
msub -l depend=${JOB_ID} /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/next_job.msub
#)&

[do hard work here: run your r script, etc.]

canceljob $(cat /path/to/next_job.msub)
```

The key here is the `next_job` line, which submits a new job that (by the dependency) will only run when the current job is finished (whether it dies or finishes gracefully).  If the "hard work" steps finish, it then cancels the follow-up job.  But, if the "hard work" steps get interrupted by wall-clock time (or for some other reason), the `canceljob` command is never reached, and the job which was submitted eventually runs.

I usually wrap the submission in parens, sleep a bit, and use `&` (ie. I uncomment the 4th, 5th and 7th lines) to decouple that process from the main script.  This way, if the "hard work" has a problem and fails within the first minute or so, that process gets terminated and you don't get an infinite chain of very-short-but-failing jobs.